# Background-color de selection não funciona

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte CSS:

```
*::selection {background-color:red;color:blue;}
*::-moz-selection {background-color:red;color:blue;}
*::-webkit-selection {background-color:red;color:blue;}
```

Onde, qualquer parte do texto, ele deixa o `background` em vermelho e o texto em azul.

Só que o `background-color` não está funcionando.

Comment: vai ver o navegador achou que azul em cima do vermelho ia ficar muito feio :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez alguma outra regra esteja sobrepondo esta pois o CSS está correto e [funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxn/LbaLeb8c/).

[image: selection]

Tente declarar essa regra logo no início do arquivo CSS, acima de qualquer outra definição.

```css
::selection {background-color:red;color:blue;}
::-moz-selection {background-color:red;color:blue;}
::-webkit-selection {background-color:red;color:blue;}

/* outras regras... */
```

```html
<p>Quisque sollicitudin elit sed orci gravida, nec accumsan enim pulvinar.
Curabitur eu turpis non nulla sodales consequat in in turpis. Ut iaculis, elit
dapibus interdum vulputate, mi nibh finibus neque, scelerisque commodo massa
odio ut diam. Cras nec massa eget tellus mattis consequat. Nulla ut dictum enim.
Proin molestie gravida sapien, at tincidunt erat ultrices vel. Integer in quam
in arcu rutrum malesuada at.</p>
```

Comment: Foi exatamente isso que aconteceu. O CSS de um plugin que eu estou usando estava aplicando um `*::selection {background-color:transparent;color:blue;}`